# Assign values to a column conditionally based on text category in R

Tags: r, text, data-manipulation, grepl

I need to assign values to a new column based on the "keyword". I did some simple trial like below. The rule is I need to tag all the keyword containing "advertising" or "marketing" as "Marketing".

```
keyword <- c("advertising plan",
           "advertising budget",
           "marketing plan",
           "marketing budget",
           "hr plan",
           "hr budget",
           "operation plan",
           "operation budget")
indicator <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
sample <- cbind(keyword,indicator)
```

I used to use this method to do the tagging.

```
sample$topic <- ifelse(grepl("(marketing|advertising)",sample$keyword),"Marketing",0)
```

But now, I have longer rules, which are stored as another string factor like below:

```
rule <- c("marketing", "advertising", "word 3", "word 4" .... "word 500")
```

It is hard to type the rules one by one in the previous code. I wonder if there is way to run all the rules together in R or I should write a loop to do this.

Comment: Use the `paste` to collapse the vector i.e. `as.integer(grepl(paste(rule, collapse="|"), sample$keyword))`

Answer (score 0):

We can collapse the `vector` in to a single string with delimiter `|` for the `pattern` in `grepl`

```
ifelse(grepl(paste(rule, collapse="|"), sample$keyword), "Marketing", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this, but the value returns as 1 instead of "Marketing".

Comment: @RyanTao  I didn't see the "Marketing" earlier, corrected it